# Elements overlap in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, css-float

I have made the HTML page. The page is working fine in Google Chrome and Firefox but internet explorer is causing some problems.
This is what i'm getting in chrome and Firefox[image: Displaying fine]

but in Internet Explorer i'm getting this :

[image: Problem Picture]

Here is my HTML and CSS code

```
    <div class="login">
            <div class="jo-dil clearfix">
                  <div class="hide-on-sm">
                    <h2>GRATIS THUISBEZORGD!</h2>
                  </div>
                    <nav id="primary_nav_wrap">
                        <ul>
                          <li><a href="#"><img src="imgs/euro1.png" /></a>
                            <ul>
                              <li><a href="#"><img src="imgs/euro.png" /></a></li>
                              <li><a href="#"><img src="imgs/euro.png" /></a></li>
                              <li><a href="#"><img src="imgs/euro.png" /></a></li>
                            </ul>
                          </li>
                          <li style="margin-top:-3px;"><a href="#"><img src="imgs/flag1.png" /></a>
                            <ul>
                              <li><a href="#"><img src="imgs/flag.png" /></a></li>
                              <li><a href="#"><img src="imgs/flag.png" /></a></li>
                              <li><a href="#"><img src="imgs/flag.png" /></a></li>
                            </ul>
                          </li>
                        </ul>
                     </nav>        
            </div>

                  <div class="account">
                      <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">INLOGGEN</a></li>
                        <li>|</li>
                        <li><a href="#">REGISTREREN</a></li>
                        <li>|</li>
                        <li><a href="#">MIJN ACCOUNT</a></li>
                      </ul>
                  </div>
      </div>
```

The CSS code is

```
    .hide-on-sm img{
          float: left; 
      }
    .jo-dil{
           display: block;
           text-align: right;
           }
           .jo-dil img{
                 float: left;
                 margin-top: 12px;
                 margin-left: 0px;
                 }

           .jo-dil h2{
                 color: #858085;
                 float: left;
                 font-family: "Calibri", sans-serif;
                 font-size: 15px;
                 font-weight: 700;
                 margin-left: 47px;
                 margin-top: 13px;
                 text-transform: uppercase;
            }
```

[Link to web](http://ha-media.net/LadyHabits/) (May not be appropriate for work.)

Please have a look and tell me the solution . Any help would be really appreciated.

Regards,

Comment: *Which* Internet Explorer? They can be very different animals.

Comment: Currently  i'm seeing it on IE 11

Answer (score 0):

Its done. I figured it out i was actually font that was not loading in IE . Now its loading and seems to be working fine !
Thanks